# Hyphenate term with numbers and white space within acronyms

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms

I want to use the command `\hyphanation` to force latex keeping terms in the same line 
The terms are for example **IAS 39** and **IFRS 9**. 
I use acornyms for IAS and IFRS and let a white space between the numbers. In code it looks like this:

```
\acs{IAS} 39 and \acs{IFRS} 9
```

In the preamble I insert this code:

```
\hyphenation{
IFRS 9
IAS 39
IAS 01
IAS 02}
```

But when I compile my document I get the error message that it is not a letter. 
If I remove the numbers it works fine. 
Now the questions:

1. How can I use this command with the needed whitespaces?
2. Can this command handle acronyms?

I know that I can use the `\mbox{}`command, but these terms appear very often, so it would be a high invest. 
Thanks for you help!!

Comment: Why don't you simply write `\acs{IAS}~39 and \acs{IFRS}~9`?

Comment: Because I didn't know that this is possible :/. Thanks for the simple and great help :D But I would still have to correct nearly 100 terms. Is there a possibality like or with \hyphanation?

Comment: It is possible (but highly unusual) to make `\hyphenation` work with digits (by using non standard lowercase codes, but it is essentially impossible to make it work with spaces. It is designed to hyphenate each word in a paragraph where space(or more generally glue)  is used to separate the words,..

Comment: A space is always a legitimate line break point. Unfortunately the only way to correct is to do a search and replace.

Comment: Than I think I will have to do a search and replace. Thanks for your comments!!!

Comment: @j0chn Are all of your acronyms followed by numbers in that fashion?

Comment: @egreg no just the IAS and IFRS examples I gave. The other acronyms are just followed by letters to create the plural like "\acs{MSKB}s". But I think latex will hyphenate them correctly.

Comment: `\newcommand{\IAS}{\acs{IAS}~}`, so you have just to change `\acs{IAS}` with `\IAS`, assuming *every* occurrence of `\acs{IAS}` is followed by a number.

Comment: But there is no difference in searching and replacing "\acs{IAS} with "\IAS" and searching and replacing "\acs{IAS}" and "\acs{IAS}~" or am I wrong with this statement?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to define hyphenation exceptions involving spaces (at least without doing nasty things with category codes).

If you define

```
\newcommand{\IAS}{\acs{IAS}~\ignorespaces}
```

you can just search and replace without worrying about possible spaces that could creep in.

Alternatively, replace `\acs{IAS}` (with a trailing space) with `\acs{IAS}~`.